# jpg images to gif ffmpeg no data found in image

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jpeg, gif

I was trying to use ffmpeg to create a gif from jpg images, but I wasn't able to convert them, not through a python code and not even from the dir itself in cmd

[running cmd in the folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47jwI.png)

python code:

```
input_files = f"{BASE_DIR}\\qr_images\\qr%d.jpg"
command = f'ffmpeg -i {input_files} output.gif'
os.system(f'start /wait cmd /k {command}')
```

[the dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNRz0.png)

I need the files in the dir to be able to convert to gif using ffmpeg (I have it installed correctly)

this is the complete cmd dialog (if I run it from the dir in cmd or if i run the python code:

ffmpeg version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3
--enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband   libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100   libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100   libavformat    60.  3.100 /
60.  3.100   libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100   libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100   libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100   libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100   libpostproc    57.  1.100 /
57.  1.100 [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] No JPEG data found in image [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 1 times [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] No JPEG data found in image [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 1 times [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] No JPEG data found in image [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] bits 159 is invalid [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 2 times [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] bits 247 is invalid [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] No JPEG data found in image [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 000002000696bfc0] No JPEG data found in image [image2 @ 000002000696aec0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg (Progressive), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options Input #0, image2, from 'c:\Test_proj\qr_images\qr%d.jpg':   Duration: 00:00:00.28, start:
0.000000, bitrate: N/A   Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn Stream mapping:  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> gif (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c5) [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (ca) Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 1 times [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (ce) [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] No JPEG data found in image Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 1 times [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cb) [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] Can not process SOS before SOF, skipping [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] No JPEG data found in image Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] bits 159 is invalid Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 2 times [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] bits 247 is invalid Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c6) [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] No JPEG data found in image Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] Can not process SOS before SOF, skipping [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] Can not process SOS before SOF, skipping
Last message repeated 2 times [mjpeg @ 00000200069a35c0] No JPEG data found in image Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF Error marking filters as finished Conversion failed!

Comment: What *does* happen? Do you receive an error message? Does nothing seem to happen at all? Does something run, but you only see a single output?

Comment: I receive an error from cmd (the one that is shown in the image) and in the end it writes "Conversion failed!" in cmd

Comment: When I try running the command in a folder that has some numbered .jpg images, it runs without error and creates an animated .gif. From the error message, it seems clear that at least some of the .jpg files are not actually .jpg images. Can you share images here that cause this problem, ensuring that you have the same problem if you run the command on the shared images?

Comment: img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
        img.save(f"{img_dir}/qr%d.jpg" % (i+1))
this is how I made the images in the dir